# Wrong option for GRASS "v.surf.idw" using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, grass-gis, python-2.7, qgis-processing

Using Qgis 2.14.12 and PyQGIS, I get an error message when executing the following:

```
processing.runalg('grass7:v.surf.idw', layer, 18, 2.0, 'p', True, "%f, %f, %f ,%f"%(1.635, 1.813, 50.896,  51.0205), 0.005, -1, 0.001, "e://out.tif")
```

The output from

```
layer.isValid()
```

is True, but I get this error (warning) in the Python Console :

```
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\bin>g.region n= 51.020500 s= 50.896000 e= 1.813000 w=1.635000 res=0.005                  
   Sorry, <51.020500> isn't a valid option                  
   Sorry, <50.896000> isn't a valid option                  
   Sorry, <1.813000> isn't a valid option
```

This results in a 1 km raster at lat/lon 0/0.

However, when I launch the function from the QGIS toolbox, the output is fine.

I've tried both with GRASS 6 & 7.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax seems to be correct, but you need to remove the blank space when specifying the extent. Try replacing:

```
"%f, %f, %f ,%f"%(1.635, 1.813, 50.896,  51.0205)
```

with:

```
"%f,%f,%f,%f" %(1.635, 1.813, 50.896,  51.0205)
```

In this way, you will write it as a string.

The working command should be:

```
processing.runalg('grass7:v.surf.idw', layer, 18, 2.0, 'p', True, "%f,%f,%f,%f"%(1.635, 1.813, 50.896,  51.0205), 0.005, -1, 0.001, "e://out.tif")
```

Comment: I tried that prior to using %f, but still giving me that error. What i don't get is that it works fine though the toolbox.

Comment: @julsbreakdown Why did you specify `0.005` as output size of the cell? a 5 mm resolution raster seems is not so common. Furthermore, `0.001` should be `0.0001` if left as default value. What about using `0` instead of `0.005` and `0.0001` instead of `0.001`?

Comment: for the default value 0.001 that was a typo, for the resolution i tried giving a aberrant value to see if it made a difference. But even with default values a still get the error/warning message

Comment: @julsbreakdown Are you sure that the extent value is correct? Are you working with a file having projected CRS?

Comment: Nope EPSG:4326, even when i use a larger extent it gives me that error

Comment: Run the algorithm from the Processing Toolbox and then go to `Processing `> `History`, open the `ALGORITHM` folder (it displays all the operations you ran from Processing). Try to find the differences with your script: is it equals to yours?

Comment: The difference is that I give a vector layer as a input, and the toolbox uses the path to the layer. This seems to do the trick thank you

Comment: I think it should be useful to others if I edit my answer including the final solution instead of the first one I provided, so you may accept it for helping other future readers.

Comment: the error in the end was the spacing in the BB (%s,%s,%s,%s) and not (%s, %s, %s, %s)

Comment: @julsbreakdown is it ok by now?

Comment: +1, there's got to be a simple fix for this extent problem =)

Comment: @Joseph Oh yes, I was blind =)

Comment: @mgri - Oh no! I meant that it would be nice if the GRASS algorithms took an empty string value or `None` as the extent parameter without having to define it constantly :)

Comment: @Joseph I got it and I agree with you but, if you see the history of this answer, you will confirm I was blind! Never thought about anything else =)